# iCarousel – Make all items selectable, not just centered one

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, icarousel

I'm using the great iOS control `iCarousel`'s `Wheel` type and I want all of the buttons it contains to be usable / selectable at any time (i.e. I can tap any of them, no matter which one is currently at the top of the wheel). The user can still scroll the wheel as normal, but no matter which button they tap, it should register.

The current behavior seems inconsistent: if I tap one of the buttons directly next to the center one (to its left or right), that button moves into the center slot. Clicking one of the buttons two positions away 'sometimes' causes it to scroll to that letter, sometimes it's ignored. Any other buttons are always ignored.

Is this possible to set up, preferably without hugely modifying the class? I'm by no means an expert, but am learning every day :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set carousel.centerItemWhenSelected = NO;

That will disable the behaviour where buttons other than the centre one are scrolled to the centre when you tap them.

As for the reason why some are not responding to taps at all, it is most likely because the frame of your carousel view is too small and the tap events are outside of the frame.

If you set carousel.clipsToBounds = YES; it will crop the carousel views to the frame as well so you'll be able to see exactly what size your carousel actually is.

Comment: Thanks for this, it has worked, but has led to a follow-up question: it appears that in wheel mode, the top item in the wheel is the center of the view, meaning that wherever I position the carousel itself, the bottom items are clipped out (or just unclickable when `clipsToBounds` is turned off). Can I change the center point of the wheel to actually be the center, rather than the top item?

Comment: In fact, if I make the view the same size as the screen, the center of the bottom view of the wheel is what's touching the bottom of my screen. Additionally, does iCarousel ignore Z-ordering? I'm putting it below my background image, just to see, and it's always right at the very top of the layers when I build.

Comment: You are correct about the wheel positioning. You can adjust that using the carousel.contentOffset property (although drag gestures will behave weirdly if the wheel is completely centered because it's not designed to work that way).

Comment: iCarousel does not ignore z-ordering. If you place a view in front of it, it should stay in front. Is it possible you placed your background image inside the iCarousel view instead of in front of it (IB does that automatically when you drag and drop)?

Comment: PS, if I answered your question I'd appreciate if you accepted my answer.